# How can I extract a subtree from my SVN repository into a new one?

Tags: svn, system-administration

We have a Subversion repository with one directory that is:

- Not really in need of revision control beyond the capabilities of RCS
- Not versioned in conjunction with anything else in the repository
- Modified about six times as often as the rest of the repository

Although I know that high revision numbers aren't a problem, nonetheless I'd like to pull this one single directory out of my main repository and into a second, ideally new one.

What is the best process for that? If it makes a difference, the SVN repository is hosted on a (... checks... ) FreeBSD machine.

It's worth noting that while I need to retain the version history in the new repository, there's no need to obliterate the content in the old; it can just sit there, for all I care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use *svnadmin dump* and *svnadmin load* to create a new repository from the original one; then copy the directory that doesn't really fit into your scheme to a better location, then delete everything else. In the original repository you would simply delete the non-fitting directory. This keeps all history intact, and you end up with two repositories.

There is probably a way to subsequently clean both repositories from the then useless parts of the history (*svndumpfilter*), but since hard disc space is quite cheap I wouldn't think this necessary. Anyway, the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html#svn-ch-5-sect-3.5) has all the information about it.

Comment: There is also the newer (SVN v. 1.7) `svnrdump` which [supposedly can do this remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939963/how-do-i-migrate-an-svn-repository-to-another-svn-repository/38288494#38288494).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to do this is to use `svnadmin dump`, then filter the dump file with the `svndumpfilter` tool (see [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering)).

For example, I had a repo with a top-level directory named 'Model', which I wanted to move to its own repo:

```
svnadmin dump my_orig_repo | svndumpfilter include --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs Model >model_only.svndump
svnadmin load my_model_repo < model_only.svndump
```

That creates the new repo with only the Model subdirectory.

For removing it from the original repository, you can simply do an `svn rm`. This will remove it from the latest version of the repo, and is the simplest way.

But if the Model directory from my example was very large, maybe I would have wanted to remove it entirely from the original. I could do that by repeating the process to create another filtered svn dump file that *excluded* it instead. Then I would replace the original with the new one that did not have the excluded directory.

Answer (score -1):

I would export (not checkout) the directory, import it into the new repository, then delete it from the original (with a log message indicating where it went, of course ;-).

That may or may not be the "best" way to do it...

Comment: No history, for example.  Sorry, that'd be a nonstarter.

Comment: I didn't realize at the time that you wanted to preserve the history :-/

Comment: No worries, it wasn't obvious.  I've amended the question.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand this correctly, but there's a nice solution to that. If your original repository was at svn://domain, and the folder you use a lot is called "folder", I believe you can simply perform the following command: `svn co svn://domain/folder` to checkout only that folder.